# Move Single Post navigation in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, themes, posts

I'm using Accesspress Mag the free edition in my Wordpress blog, I want to move the pagination used to split the posts using the  `<!--nextpage-->` , I looked everywhere inside the theme files , I couldn't find where the pagination is generated so I can move it above the social sharing bar

[image]

Would you please help

Thnx

Comment: You could try to use JavaScript to move it without touching the source files

Comment: Would you please provide some more clarification on how to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean this theme? https://wordpress.org/themes/accesspress-mag/

Comment: @Omnisite : Yes that one

Comment: @Dxtr And the screenshot is from a single post view? Because in single.php I see a call to a pagination function

Comment: @Omnisite : The pagination function called in single.php is it for Posts (previous and next Post) or is it for Post content (page 1,2,3..) ?

Comment: @Dxtr I assume next/prev. But that is why I need to know where your screenshot is from. Is that single, category, homepage, ?

Comment: @Omnisite The screenshot is from a single

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124104/discussion-between-omnisite-and-dxtr).

Answer (score 0):

You can append the bar to the HTML element you want using JQuery like this:

If you click the red box, it will append the green box to the red box. Removing the `redBox.on('click'...` method around the `redBox.append()` will make it instantaniously, but because I want you to see what is happening here you have to click the red box to move the green box.

```js
var greenBox = $('.green');

var redBox = $('.red');

redBox.on('click', function(){
  redBox.append(greenBox);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.green {
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
</div>

<div class="green">
</div>
```

You can use this technique for your pagination as well, but make sure you check out what `$.append` and `$.prepend` do in the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/).